# Using sed, how can I replace a line containing a pattern with contents from another file?

Tags: text-processing, sed

**input_file.txt**:

```
one fffds
two xxxx
three ffff
four ffde
```

**data_file.txt**:

```
six
seven
```

I want to replace the line containing `two xxxx` in **input_file.txt** with the content of **data_file.txt**.  The output file should look like this:

**output_file.txt**:

```
one fffds
six
seven
three ffff
four ffde
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
sed -n '
  /two xxxx/{
    rdata_file.txt
    d
  }
  p'
```

If the line matches the expression, the content of the file is printed and the next cycle is started. Otherwise, the second command is invoked that prints the line.

A bit more readable solution doing a similar thing in Perl:

```
perl -pe '/two xxxx/ and $_=`cat data_file.txt`'
```

Comment: the perl statement works at the command line. For the sed command, what could be the issue as it is not working for me.     i am getting the following error when i type this. sed -n '/two xxxx/{r data_file.txt d};p' input_file.txt > output_file.txt

 sed: 0602-413 There are too many '{'.

Comment: @Ramesh: The end of line after the file name is crucial. Do you have it in your command? What version of `sed` do you run?

Comment: The syntax was not POSIX (you need ";" or NL before "}", and you can't have anything (other than NL or a new expression) after "}").